# MVC in iOS: How to identify which model object corresponds to a touched view?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, binding

I'm working on a game consisting of a bunch of cards laid out on a playing area. Each card is a subclass of UIView. I track the position of each card in a Core Data model object as well, so I can save its position any time it moves.

I'm trying to maintain good MVC separation, but am wondering what the best way is to identify in the controller which model object corresponds to a card view. i.e. When a card view is moved on the playing area, its pan gesture recognizer calls a method in the controller. This method should then update the new position coordinates in the card model object (and save the card to the db).

I can think of a few ways to provide the view-to-model reference:

- Store the card model object in a property of each card view object.
  (But this puts the model in the view, no?)
- Store the card model's URL identifier in a property of the card view object. (Same as previous, but just a reference, lighter weight)
- Create a dictionary lookup
  table in the controller that maps card views to card model objects.
  (Too clunky?)

Is there a better way? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is to copy the behavior of table views.

You can have a method that ask for every card, and in that method you create and return the cards (views) retrieved from the core data (model) in the view controller (controller)

That method should be called from the class that paints the playing area.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that when someone interacts with the card view, I need to know which model object is associated with it. The difficulty is not in placing each model's card view on the screen. e.g. Each card has a tap gesture recognizer. When the recognizer's action method is called, I need to figure out inside that method which model object goes with that view. Currently, for the card view, I subclassed UIView and gave it a property of the model object's class. That way, I have an immediate pointer to the associated model object. But this joins Model and View. Is there a better way?